# Looking for a ruby regex to highlight all words that appear before and after something

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to parse some code using regex. The code I extracted is the body of a function call and has the form:

> var1, var2, var3 },  *anything here*

vars define the local variables, the definition of local variables end in the first "}," followed by a block that can contain anything, including "},".

What I am trying to do is find all instances of vars listed in local variables. So in the above example, regex would find var1, var2 and var3 as variables and return anywhere they appear in the anything block. The variables will always have the format ([a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*) and other than variable names only other characters included in the local variable section is [,\s].

I am really struggling with it though. I can't figure out two things: How to find all instances of the vars and how to repeat for all vars. I have this regex so far:

```
([a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\b[^\}\,]*\}\,(.*?\1)*
```

This regex finds the first and last appearance of a var. So applied to above, I would get the var1 at the beginning and the last var1 that appears in the anything block. I would really appreciate some feedback to get back on track.

EDIT: Here is an example

```
pairs, gatheredPairs, adjacencyList},
pairs =Flatten[{{First[#], Last[#]}, {Last[#], First[#]}} & /@ graph, 1];
gatheredPairs = GatherBy[pairs, First];
adjacencyList = {First[First[#]], Last /@ #} & /@ gatheredPairs
```

What I would like the regex to find is "pairs", "gatheredPairs" and "adjacencyList" in the entire codeblock.

Comment: Maybe regex is not the right tool for your problem? The grammar you're describing (`aBa` such that `a` is a terminal and `B` corresponds to another rule) is irregular and cannot be matched with (standard) regular expressions.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you provide an example that includes the desired result?

Comment: Added an example. Let me know if thats more helpful.

Comment: This is a job for tokenizers and lexers. You can probably match your specific sample with regular expressions, but it can never be completely robust against irregular inputs like the one you posted.